# CAKEPHP paginator custom link

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I want an custom link for my paginator. I use the folowing code

```
$this->Paginator->options(array(
        'url'=>array(
            "/custom",24,"custom1"
        ),
        'escape'=>false
    )
);
```

This results in a link with the original controller in front of the link like this:

```
 /controller/action/%2Fcustom/24/custom1
```

I want the linkt to be /custom/24/custom1. So without the escaped(/) and as a root.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try

```
'url' => '/custom/24/custom1'
```

? The syntax that you use is not valid I think. The available formats are:

```
'url' => 'action'
```

or

```
'url' => '/controller/action'
```

or

```
'url' => array(
    'controller' => 'your_controller',
    'action' => 'your_action'
)
```

See http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1387/options-url and http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1448/url.

If none of these formats satisfies you, you can consider creating a custom route, see http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/948/Defining-Routes.

Cheers

Comment: I'm using cakephp 2.2 and 'url' => `'/custom/24/custom1'` doesn't work. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: That's because the Cake Router probably needs a rule to map `'/custom/24/custom1'` to the proper controller and method. Check the last link about defining routes. Cheers